# Typoscript IMAGE object: disable height/width attributes

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there any way to prevent typo3/typoscript IMAGE object from adding the dimension attributes (height and width) to the generated image tag?

**UPDATE (Thanks to cascaval)!**

The solution is to use IMG_RESOURCE instead of IMAGE. It apparently has less bells an whistles but gives you complete control of the the generated image tag.

```
   10 = IMG_RESOURCE
   10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
   10.file.import.current = 1
   10.file.import.listNum = 0
   10.stdWrap.required = 1
   10.stdWrap.wrap (
      <img src="|" />
   )
```

Note: This is for use with Templavoila.

Comment: The result of `IMG_RESOURCE` is just a path, a **resource**. That's why it actually cannot have any other bells and whistles as `IMAGE` has. All the non-standard modifications are then done with `stdWrap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** but you can use **[IMG_RESOURCE](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/7/#id2633654)** object instead and wrap the resulting image path so that you get a HTML tag you want. Example:

```
temp.image_test = IMG_RESOURCE
temp.image_test {
  stdWrap.wrap = <img src="|" />
  file = GIFBUILDER
  file {
    format = jpg
    quality = 90
    maxWidth = 9999
    maxHeight = 9999
    XY = [10.w],[10.h]

    10 = IMAGE
    10.file {
      import = uploads/pics/
      import.field = image
      import.listNum = 0
    }

    20 = SCALE
    20 {
      width = 200
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It work with IMG_RESOURCE though it had to change the code somewhat (see update in post)

Comment: My code is just a theoretical example. It only demonstrates the main "trick" and that is `stdWrap.wrap` to wrap the path.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong! It also works with IMAGE:

```
10 = IMAGE
10 {
    file = path/to/image.file
    stdWrap.replacement {
        10 {
            search = # width="[0-9]*?"#i
            replace = 
            useRegExp = 1
        }
        20 {
            search = # height="[0-9]*?"#i
            replace = 
            useRegExp = 1
        }
    }
}
```